# Create Virtual Machine in Existing Storage account

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I'm using the "AzureResourceGroup" template Project in VisualStudio from the Azure tools under the cloud subheading in the C# projects.

What i would like to do is create templates for my virtual development environment but it seems the resource manager templates require you to create a new storage account for every virtual machine, Am i able to create a template that creates new virtual machines without creating new storage accounts as i already have one.

Code i have is as follows,

Powershell Script {Mostly unmodified from the template}:

```
#Requires -Version 3.0
#Requires -Module AzureRM.Resources
#Requires -Module Azure.Storage

Param(
    [string] $ResourceGroupLocation = "Australia Southeast",
    [string] $ResourceGroupName = 'vmdevelop',
    [switch] $UploadArtifacts,
    [string] $StorageAccountName,
    [string] $StorageAccountResourceGroupName, 
    [string] $StorageContainerName = $ResourceGroupName.ToLowerInvariant() + '-stageartifacts',
    [string] $TemplateFile = '..\Templates\WindowsVirtualMachine.json',
    [string] $TemplateParametersFile = '..\Templates\WindowsVirtualMachine.parameters.json',
    [string] $ArtifactStagingDirectory = '..\bin\Debug\staging',
    [string] $AzCopyPath = '..\Tools\AzCopy.exe',
    [string] $DSCSourceFolder = '..\DSC'
)

Import-Module Azure -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

try {
    [Microsoft.Azure.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::ClientFactory.AddUserAgent("VSAzureTools-$UI$($host.name)".replace(" ","_"), "2.8")
} catch { }

Set-StrictMode -Version 3

$OptionalParameters = New-Object -TypeName Hashtable
$TemplateFile = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSScriptRoot, $TemplateFile)
$TemplateParametersFile = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSScriptRoot, $TemplateParametersFile)

if ($UploadArtifacts) {
    # Convert relative paths to absolute paths if needed
    $AzCopyPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSScriptRoot, $AzCopyPath)
    $ArtifactStagingDirectory = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSScriptRoot, $ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    $DSCSourceFolder = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSScriptRoot, $DSCSourceFolder)

    Set-Variable ArtifactsLocationName '_artifactsLocation' -Option ReadOnly -Force
    Set-Variable ArtifactsLocationSasTokenName '_artifactsLocationSasToken' -Option ReadOnly -Force

    $OptionalParameters.Add($ArtifactsLocationName, $null)
    $OptionalParameters.Add($ArtifactsLocationSasTokenName, $null)

    # Parse the parameter file and update the values of artifacts location and artifacts location SAS token if they are present
    $JsonContent = Get-Content $TemplateParametersFile -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
    $JsonParameters = $JsonContent | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "parameters"}

    if ($JsonParameters -eq $null) {
        $JsonParameters = $JsonContent
    }
    else {
        $JsonParameters = $JsonContent.parameters
    }

    $JsonParameters | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty | ForEach-Object {
        $ParameterValue = $JsonParameters | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $_.Name

        if ($_.Name -eq $ArtifactsLocationName -or $_.Name -eq $ArtifactsLocationSasTokenName) {
            $OptionalParameters[$_.Name] = $ParameterValue.value
        }
    }

    $StorageAccountKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $StorageAccountResourceGroupName -Name $StorageAccountName).Key1

    $StorageAccountContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $StorageAccountResourceGroupName -Name $StorageAccountName).Context

    # Create DSC configuration archive
    if (Test-Path $DSCSourceFolder) {
        Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
        $ArchiveFile = Join-Path $ArtifactStagingDirectory "dsc.zip"
        Remove-Item -Path $ArchiveFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($DSCSourceFolder, $ArchiveFile)
    }

    # Generate the value for artifacts location if it is not provided in the parameter file
    $ArtifactsLocation = $OptionalParameters[$ArtifactsLocationName]
    if ($ArtifactsLocation -eq $null) {
        $ArtifactsLocation = $StorageAccountContext.BlobEndPoint + $StorageContainerName
        $OptionalParameters[$ArtifactsLocationName] = $ArtifactsLocation
    }

    # Use AzCopy to copy files from the local storage drop path to the storage account container
    & $AzCopyPath """$ArtifactStagingDirectory""", $ArtifactsLocation, "/DestKey:$StorageAccountKey", "/S", "/Y", "/Z:$env:LocalAppData\Microsoft\Azure\AzCopy\$ResourceGroupName"
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { return }

    # Generate the value for artifacts location SAS token if it is not provided in the parameter file
    $ArtifactsLocationSasToken = $OptionalParameters[$ArtifactsLocationSasTokenName]
    if ($ArtifactsLocationSasToken -eq $null) {
        # Create a SAS token for the storage container - this gives temporary read-only access to the container
        $ArtifactsLocationSasToken = New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Container $StorageContainerName -Context $StorageAccountContext -Permission r -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddHours(4)
        $ArtifactsLocationSasToken = ConvertTo-SecureString $ArtifactsLocationSasToken -AsPlainText -Force
        $OptionalParameters[$ArtifactsLocationSasTokenName] = $ArtifactsLocationSasToken
    }
}

# Create or update the resource group using the specified template file and template parameters file
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -Location $ResourceGroupLocation -Verbose -Force -ErrorAction Stop 

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $TemplateFile).BaseName + '-' + ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString('MMdd-HHmm')) `
                                   -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                                   -TemplateFile $TemplateFile `
                                   -TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParametersFile `
                                   @OptionalParameters `
                                   -Force -Verbose
```

The template.json {this has been extensively modified to add more parameters instead of defining most changes in the Variables}

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Username for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "ResourceGroupLocation": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "ResourceGroup location"
      }
    },
    "OSDiskName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "ResourceGroup location"
      }
    },
    "vmSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "ResourceGroup location"
      }
    },
    "nicName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "ResourceGroup location"
      }
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Password for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "publicIPAddressName": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Password for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "dnsNameForPublicIP": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Globally unique DNS Name for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "windowsOSVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "2016-Technical-Preview-with-Containers",
      "allowedValues": [
        "2008-R2-SP1",
        "2012-Datacenter",
        "2012-R2-Datacenter",
        "2016-Technical-Preview-with-Containers"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Windows version for the VM. This will pick a fully patched image of this given Windows version. Allowed values: 2008-R2-SP1, 2012-Datacenter, 2012-R2-Datacenter."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "imagePublisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
    "imageOffer": "WindowsServer",
    "OSDiskName": "[parameters('OSDiskName')]",
    "nicName": "[parameters('nicName')]",
    "addressPrefix": "10.2.0.0/16",
    "subnetName": "Develop1",
    "subnetPrefix": "10.2.0.0/24",
    "vhdStorageType": "Standard_LRS",
    "publicIPAddressName": "[parameters('publicIPAddressName')]",
    "publicIPAddressType": "Dynamic",
    "vhdStorageContainerName": "vhds",
    "vmName": "ContainerHost01",
    "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]",
    "virtualNetworkName": "DevelopmentNetwork",
    "vnetId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]",
    "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetId'), '/subnets/', variables('subnetName'))]",
    "vhdStorageName": "ContainerServer01",
    "diagnosticsStorageAccountName": "[variables('vhdStorageName')]",
    "diagnosticsStorageAccountResourceGroup": "[variables('vhdStorageName')]",
    "accountid": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', variables('diagnosticsStorageAccountResourceGroup'), '/providers/', 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('diagnosticsStorageAccountName'))]",
    "wadlogs": "<WadCfg> <DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration overallQuotaInMB=\"4096\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration\"> <DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter=\"Error\"/> <WindowsEventLog scheduledTransferPeriod=\"PT1M\" > <DataSource name=\"Application!*[System[(Level = 1 or Level = 2)]]\" /> <DataSource name=\"Security!*[System[(Level = 1 or Level = 2)]]\" /> <DataSource name=\"System!*[System[(Level = 1 or Level = 2)]]\" /></WindowsEventLog>",
    "wadperfcounters1": "<PerformanceCounters scheduledTransferPeriod=\"PT1M\"><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"Percent\"><annotation displayName=\"CPU utilization\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\Processor(_Total)\\% Privileged Time\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"Percent\"><annotation displayName=\"CPU privileged time\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\Processor(_Total)\\% User Time\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"Percent\"><annotation displayName=\"CPU user time\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\Processor Information(_Total)\\Processor Frequency\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"Count\"><annotation displayName=\"CPU frequency\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\System\\Processes\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"Count\"><annotation displayName=\"Processes\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\Process(_Total)\\Thread Count\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"Count\"><annotation displayName=\"Threads\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\Process(_Total)\\Handle Count\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"Count\"><annotation displayName=\"Handles\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\Memory\\% Committed Bytes In Use\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"Percent\"><annotation displayName=\"Memory usage\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\Memory\\Available Bytes\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"Bytes\"><annotation displayName=\"Memory available\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\Memory\\Committed Bytes\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"Bytes\"><annotation displayName=\"Memory committed\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\Memory\\Commit Limit\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"Bytes\"><annotation displayName=\"Memory commit limit\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\\% Disk Time\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"Percent\"><annotation displayName=\"Disk active time\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration>",
    "wadperfcounters2": "<PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\\% Disk Read Time\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"Percent\"><annotation displayName=\"Disk active read time\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\\% Disk Write Time\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"Percent\"><annotation displayName=\"Disk active write time\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Transfers/sec\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"CountPerSecond\"><annotation displayName=\"Disk operations\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Reads/sec\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"CountPerSecond\"><annotation displayName=\"Disk read operations\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Writes/sec\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"CountPerSecond\"><annotation displayName=\"Disk write operations\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Bytes/sec\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"BytesPerSecond\"><annotation displayName=\"Disk speed\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Read Bytes/sec\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"BytesPerSecond\"><annotation displayName=\"Disk read speed\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Write Bytes/sec\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"BytesPerSecond\"><annotation displayName=\"Disk write speed\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier=\"\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\% Free Space\" sampleRate=\"PT15S\" unit=\"Percent\"><annotation displayName=\"Disk free space (percentage)\" locale=\"en-us\"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration></PerformanceCounters>",
    "wadcfgxstart": "[concat(variables('wadlogs'), variables('wadperfcounters1'), variables('wadperfcounters2'), '<Metrics resourceId=\"')]",
    "wadmetricsresourceid": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', variables('diagnosticsStorageAccountResourceGroup'), '/providers/', 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]",
    "wadcfgxend": "><MetricAggregation scheduledTransferPeriod=\"PT1H\"/><MetricAggregation scheduledTransferPeriod=\"PT1M\"/></Metrics></DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration></WadCfg>"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "[variables('vhdStorageName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "location": "[parameters('ResourceGroupLocation')]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "[variables('vhdStorageName')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "accountType": "[variables('vhdStorageType')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "name": "[variables('publicIPAddressName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('ResourceGroupLocation')]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "PublicIPAddress"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "[variables('publicIPAddressType')]",
        "dnsSettings": {
          "domainNameLabel": "[parameters('dnsNameForPublicIP')]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('ResourceGroupLocation')]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "VirtualNetwork"
      },
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[variables('addressPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('subnetName')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[variables('subnetPrefix')]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "name": "[variables('nicName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('ResourceGroupLocation')]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "NetworkInterface"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "publicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]"
              },
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "name": "[variables('vmName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('ResourceGroupLocation')]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "VirtualMachine"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('vhdStorageName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[variables('vmSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[variables('vmName')]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "[variables('imagePublisher')]",
            "offer": "[variables('imageOffer')]",
            "sku": "[parameters('windowsOSVersion')]",
            "version": "latest"
          },
          "osDisk": {
            "name": "osdisk",
            "vhd": {
              "uri": "[concat('http://', variables('vhdStorageName'), '.blob.core.windows.net/', variables('vhdStorageContainerName'), '/', variables('OSDiskName'), '.vhd')]"
            },
            "caching": "ReadWrite",
            "createOption": "FromImage"
          }
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('nicName'))]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "diagnosticsProfile": {
          "bootDiagnostics": {
            "enabled": true,
            "storageUri": "[concat('http://', variables('diagnosticsStorageAccountName'), '.blob.core.windows.net')]"
          }
        }
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "extensions",
          "name": "Microsoft.Insights.VMDiagnosticsSettings",
          "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
          "location": "[parameters('ResourceGroupLocation')]",
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "AzureDiagnostics"
          },
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics",
            "type": "IaaSDiagnostics",
            "typeHandlerVersion": "1.5",
            "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
            "settings": {
              "xmlCfg": "[base64(concat(variables('wadcfgxstart'), variables('wadmetricsresourceid'), variables('wadcfgxend')))]",
              "storageAccount": "[variables('diagnosticsStorageAccountName')]"
            },
            "protectedSettings": {
              "storageAccountName": "[variables('diagnosticsStorageAccountName')]",
              "storageAccountKey": "[listkeys(variables('accountid'), '2015-06-15').key1]",
              "storageAccountEndPoint": "https://core.windows.net"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Th Following is the Powershell error i get when i don't specify a new resource parameter to be created.

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : InvalidTemplate: Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/vmdevelop' is not defined in a template.'.
At C:\Users\James\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AzureResourceGroup2\AzureResourceGroup1\Scripts\Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1:98 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $TemplateFil ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Hyak.Common.CloudException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCommand
```

The Following is the output of the script if i define a pre-existing storage account.

```
PS C:\Users\James> C:\Users\James\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AzureResourceGroup2\AzureResourceGroup1\Scripts\Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1
VERBOSE: 9:19:58 AM - Created resource group 'VMDEVELOP' in location 'australiasoutheast'


ResourceGroupName : VMDEVELOP
Location          : australiasoutheast
ProvisioningState : Succeeded
Tags              : 
Resources         : 
                    Name                Type                               Location          
                    ==================  =================================  ==================
                    DevelopmentNetwork  Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks  australiasoutheast
                    vmdevelop           Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts  australiasoutheast

ResourceId        : /subscriptions/<ID>/resourceGroups/VMDEVELOP

cmdlet New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
VERBOSE: 9:20:05 AM - Create template deployment 'WindowsVirtualMachine-1214-2219'.
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 9:20:10 AM - Resource Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts 'vmdevelop' failed with message 'The storage account named vmdevelop already exists under the 
subscription.'
At C:\Users\James\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AzureResourceGroup2\AzureResourceGroup1\Scripts\Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1:98 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $TemplateFil ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCommand

VERBOSE: 9:20:14 AM - Resource Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks 'DevelopmentNetwork' provisioning status is succeeded
VERBOSE: 9:20:14 AM - Resource Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses 'Cont01VMPublicIP' provisioning status is running
VERBOSE: 9:20:27 AM - Resource Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces 'ContVMNic01' provisioning status is succeeded
VERBOSE: 9:20:27 AM - Resource Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses 'Cont01VMPublicIP' provisioning status is succeeded

DeploymentName     : WindowsVirtualMachine-1214-2219
CorrelationId      : <ID>
ResourceGroupName  : vmdevelop
ProvisioningState  : Failed
Timestamp          : 14/12/2015 10:20:43 PM
Mode               : Incremental
TemplateLink       : 
TemplateLinkString : 
Parameters         : {[adminUsername, Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.Models.DeploymentVariable], [storageAccountName, Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.Models.DeploymentVariable], 
                     [resourceGroupLocation, Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.Models.DeploymentVariable], [osDiskName, Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.Models.DeploymentVariable]...}
ParametersString   : 
                     Name             Type                       Value     
                     ===============  =========================  ==========
                     adminUsername    String                     admin  
                     storageAccountName  String                     vmdevelop 
                     resourceGroupLocation  String                     Australia Southeast
                     osDiskName       String                     Container01VHD
                     vmSize           String                     Standard_A1
                     nicName          String                     ContVMNic01
                     adminPassword    SecureString                         
                     publicIPAddressName  SecureString                         
                     dnsNameForPublicIP  String                     containerserver01
                     windowsOSVersion  String                     2016-Technical-Preview-with-Containers
                     vmdevelopType    String                     Standard_LRS

Outputs            : 
OutputsString      : 




PS C:\Users\James>
```

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve ? you want to create a c# project ? I do appreciate u r sharing your code.But, please be more specific on your requirement.

Comment: @Atf - the question is very clear - asking whether VMs can be used with existing storage account vs creating new one.

Comment: @James - Just curious - what gave you the impression you can't use an existing storage account when creating new VM's via ARM?

Comment: All of the Resource manager Templates provided by MS and all the blogs i have managed to find on the subject create a new storage account for each virtual machine created, I tried removing that parameter and pointing it at a pre created storage account and the powershell cmdlet complained that i did not create a storage account.

Comment: If that were the case, we'd need tens of thousands of storage accounts. Can you post the powershell error please?

Comment: I understand that i have sucessfully created multiple vm's with resource manager on the same storage account with no difficulty its only when i try to automate the process with the above example, and yes i can post the error i get when i remove to storage account perameter as soon as im back in the office in a little under 8 hours.

Comment: @eXplicit 

I have appended the Powershell error to the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After following Michael B's Link and beginning a new template i came across the dependsOn directive and i scanned through my original template and found

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
  "name": "[variables('vmName')]",
  "location": "[parameters('ResourceGroupLocation')]",
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "VirtualMachine"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('vhdStorageName'))]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'))]"
  ],
```

The issue when i removed the Storage resource from the template and ran the script it thew a:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : InvalidTemplate: Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/vmdevelop' is not defined in a template.'.
```

The Reason for this was the following line (187 in the template above that still has the storage resource)

```
"[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('vhdStorageName'))]",
```

Removing this line that was causing the the dependency for a new storage account to be created has resolved the issue and i can now deploy VM's into the pre-allocated Storage container i have for virtual machines.

Thank you everybody that contributed, I very much appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

In your template you have this in the virtual machine node -

```
      "osDisk": {
        "name": "osdisk",
        "vhd": {
          "uri": "[concat('http://', variables('vhdStorageName'), '.blob.core.windows.net/', variables('vhdStorageContainerName'), '/', variables('OSDiskName'), '.vhd')]"
        },
```

if `variables('vhdStorageName')` already exists then it will simply create the Vhd on that storage account.

The visual studio templates add far too many layers of complexity to the whole thing. My advice would be to first create some simple templates by hand, and then run them by hand with `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` get a feel for how they work and then you'll be much better placed to be able to debug more complex scripts.

Comment: Thanks Michael,
Unfortunately that does not help me resolve the storage account creation dependency i have issues with at the moment though you explanation did answer another question i had :) Perhaps you could post an example of a simplified Template so that its more clear that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm away from my comp for a few hours now, but [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/resource-group-linked-templates/) might help with how to define pre-existing resources

Comment: Thanks for the link it did help in the end i started writing a new template but i found the dependsOn directive and that was my issue ill post a full explanation as an answer :)